# Angular: service injection via InjectionToken fails

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

**Angular version: 4.4.6**

**Edit:** This is a complex example which might be of no interest to you.

**TL;DR:** My service could not be dynamically injected only because it wasn't provided by any module (I got confused with the passing of the service reference via an InjectionToken, *which does not* do the providing of the service).

---

My **ResourceService** services are designed as **proxyes** to **ResourceProviders** services, whose list can be configured dynamically via the **ResourceModule**.forRoot method.

**resource-provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class ResourceProvider {
  // whatever...
}
```

**resource.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { SourceResourceService, SOURCE_TOKEN } from './source-resource.service';

@NgModule({
})
export class ResourceModule {
  /**
   * forRoot awaits a list of [[ResourceProvider]]s to be used by the
   * various [[ResourceService]]s.
   */
  static forRoot( sourceProviders: any[] ):
      ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ResourceModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: SOURCE_TOKEN, useValue: sourceProviders },
        SourceResourceService
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**resource-service.ts**

```
import { Injector, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ResourceProvider } from './resource-provider';

/**
 * Base class for ResourceServices
 */
export abstract class ResourceService {

  injector: Injector;
  resourceProviders = new Array<ResourceProvider>();

  constructor( injector: Injector ) {
    // Injector is used to inject [[ResourceProvider]]s in the list 'resourceProviders',
    // during the initialization of the Service.
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  protected initResourceProviders(list: any[]) {
    let providerClass: any; // what type should that be in Typescript?
    for( providerClass of list ) {
      let service;
      try {
        //!\ BREAKS HERE /!\
        service = this.injector.get(providerClass);
        //!\ BREAKS HERE /!\
        if(!service) {
          console.error( "ResourceService: " + providerClass + " is not a registered service");
        } else {
          this.resourceProviders.push( service );
        }
      }
      catch( err ) {
        console.error( "ResourceService: " + providerClass + " is not a registered service", err);
      }
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

**source-resource.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Injector, Inject, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ResourceService } from './resource-service';

export const SOURCE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('SOURCE_RESOURCE_PROVIDERS_TOKEN');

@Injectable()
export class SourceResourceService extends ResourceService {

  constructor(
    private injectorParam: Injector,
    @Inject(SOURCE_TOKEN) SOURCE: any[]
  ){
    super( injectorParam );
    this.initResourceProviders(SOURCE);
  }
  //...
}
```

**source-resource.service.spec.ts** (testing with Karma)

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ResourceModule } from './resource.module';
import { SourceResourceService } from './source-resource.service';
import { ResourceProvider } from './resource-provider';

@Injectable()
class p0 extends ResourceProvider {
  //...
}

/**
 * Configure the ResourceProviders in the ResourceModule for the tests.
 */
function setTestResourceProviders(source: any[]): SourceResourceService {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports:[
      ResourceModule.forRoot(source)
    ]
  });
  return TestBed.get(SourceResourceService);
}

describe('ResourceService', () => {
  let resourceService: SourceResourceService;
  it("should proceed without throwing exception", ()=>{
    resourceService = setTestResourceProviders([p0]);
    //...
  });
});
```

Despite the fact I pass my ResourceProvider list (containing p0) within the useValue of my ResourceModule definition, the this.injector.get(p0) throws an exception **Error: No provider for p0!** (seeable in console) and my resourceService can not be used and tested further.

Why does the injection of ResourceProvider via 'useValue' fails here?

*Bonus question: what would be the Typescript type for the ResourceProvider list I provide to 'useValue'?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer's found:** there was a confusion in the ResourceModule.forRoot() creation of the ModuleWithProviders: I was providing some tokens containing a list of my services references, but I wasn't *providing those very services*. Therefore those could not be found by the Injector.

Corrected code for **resource.module.ts** is:

```
static forRoot( sourceProviders: any[]):
    ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: ResourceModule,
    providers: [
      {
        provide: SOURCE_TOKEN,
        useValue: sourceProviders
      }
      SourceResourceService,
      ...sourceProviders,
    ]
  };
}
```

While attempting to generate the 'providers' array before the return statement, AoT building failed with error: **Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ResourceModule', function calls are not supported.**, so it seems the process is somewhat sensitive. I solved it by using the spread operators (...sourceProviders) within the 'providers' array directly.